# How to add third-party Java JAR files for use in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I have some third-party database client libraries in Java. I want to access them through

```
java_gateway.py
```

E.g.: to make the client class (not a JDBC driver!) available to the Python client via the Java gateway:

```
java_import(gateway.jvm, "org.mydatabase.MyDBClient")
```

It is not clear where to add the third-party libraries to the JVM classpath. I tried to add to file *compute-classpath.sh*, but that did not seem to work. I get:

> Py4jError: Trying to call a package

Also, when comparing to Hive: the hive JAR files are *not* loaded via file *compute-classpath.sh*, so that makes me suspicious. There seems to be some other mechanism happening to set up the JVM side classpath.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can add external jars as arguments to pyspark

```
pyspark --jars file1.jar,file2.jar
```

Comment: not in a position to check at this moment - but that sounds correct. The errors we were having actually had nothing to do with this, but in any case that does invalidate your answer.

Comment: Note that there are no spaces after the commas!  It will fail if you put spaces in there.

Answer (score 43):

You could add the path to jar file using Spark configuration at Runtime.

Here is an example :

```
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.jars", "/path-to-jar/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.2.1.jar")

sc = SparkContext( conf=conf)
```

Refer the [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) for more information.

Comment: Does this require uploading and deploying the jars to the driver and workers?  is the "/path-to-jar/.." the path on the driver node?

Comment: @justincress Hi, I ran it as a standalone cluster but I feel the driver is where the jar files need to be present as the workers/executors do as told by the driver.

Answer (score 14):

You could add `--jars xxx.jar` when using spark-submit

```
./bin/spark-submit --jars xxx.jar your_spark_script.py
```

or  set the enviroment variable `SPARK_CLASSPATH`

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH='/path/xxx.jar:/path/xx2.jar' your_spark_script.py
```

`your_spark_script.py` was written by pyspark API

Comment: @stanislav Thanks for your modification.

Comment: I have spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6 and --jars doesn't work for me.
The second option (setting SPARK_CLASSPATH) works.
Anyone have any idea why first option doesn't work?

Answer (score 7):

Apart from the accepted answer, you also have below options:

1. if you are in virtual environment then you can place it in

   e.g. `lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/jars`
2. if you want java to discover it then you can place where your jre is installed under `ext/` directory

Answer (score 6):

All the above answers did not work for me

What I had to do with pyspark was

```
pyspark --py-files /path/to/jar/xxxx.jar
```

For Jupyter Notebook:

```
spark = (SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("Spark_Test")
    .master('yarn-client')
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "4")
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "2")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","8")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate())

# Do this 

spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("/path/to/jar/xxxx.jar")
```

Link to the source where I found it:
https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/issues/104

Comment: addPyFile is for python dependencies, not jars https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/api/pyspark/pyspark.context.SparkContext-class.html#addPyFile

Answer (score 5):

1. **Extract** the downloaded jar file.
2. Edit system environment variable

   - Add a variable named **SPARK_CLASSPATH** and set its value to           \path\to\the\extracted\jar\file.

Eg: you have extracted the jar file in C drive in folder named sparkts
its value should be: **C:\sparkts**

3. **Restart** your cluster

Answer (score 4):

One more thing you can do is to add the Jar in the pyspark jar folder where pyspark is installed. Usually /python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/jars

Be careful if you are using a virtual environment that the jar needs to go to the pyspark installation in the virtual environment.

This way you can use the jar without sending it in command line or load it in your code.

Comment: I stumbled in here after googling for “add jar to existing sparksession” so if this works I shall be delighted. Will try it out later today.

Comment: yep. adding the jar to the jars directory worked. I was then able to call a function in my jar that takes a `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` like this: `spark._sc._jvm.com.mypackage.MyObject.myFunction(myPySparkDataFrame._jdf)`

Answer (score 2):

I've worked around this by dropping the jars into a directory drivers and then creating a spark-defaults.conf file in conf folder. Steps to follow;

```
To get the conf path:  
cd ${SPARK_HOME}/conf

vi spark-defaults.conf  
spark.driver.extraClassPath /Users/xxx/Documents/spark_project/drivers/*
```

run your Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

java/scala libs from pyspark both `--jars` and `spark.jars` are not working in version 2.4.0 and earlier (I didn't check newer version). I'm surprised how many guys are claiming that it is working.

The main problem is that for classloader retrieved in following way:

```py
jvm = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()._jvm
clazz = jvm.my.scala.class
# or
clazz = jvm.java.lang.Class.forName('my.scala.class')
```

it works only when you copy jar files to ${SPARK_HOME}/jars (this one works for me).

But when your only way is using `--jars` or `spark.jars` there is another classloader used (which is child class loader) which is set in current thread. So your python code needs to look like:

```py
clazz = jvm.java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(f"{object_name}$")
```

Hope it explains your troubles. Give me a shout if not.