# How to save data-frame in MySQL using PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I am new to Apache Spark. I have a use case where I have to save data frame data in MySQL. I got the below code to do the same:

```
data_frame.write.format('jdbc').options(
    url='URI',
    driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
    dbtable=table_name,
    user=user_name,
    password='your_password').mode('append').save()
```

But when I ran the code, I got the below error:

```
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.1/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o207.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I might be missing out on very minute detail. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error description is clearly indicating that it's not able to locate the JDBC driver class. You will have to include the JAR file for com.mysql.jdbc.Driver using

```
pyspark --jars  <jar-file-location>
```

See this question - *[How to add third-party Java JAR files for use in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698111/how-to-add-third-party-java-jars-for-use-in-pyspark)*.