# How to run python spark script with specific jars

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I have to run a python script on EMR instance using pyspark to query dynamoDB. I am able to do that by querying dynamodb on pyspark which is executed by including jars with following [command](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=225867).

```
`pyspark --jars /usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hive.jar,/usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar`
```

I ran following python3 script to query data using pyspark python module.

```
import time
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, HiveContext

start_time = time.time()
SparkContext.setSystemProperty("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://nn1:9083")
sparkSession = (SparkSession
                .builder
                .appName('example-pyspark-read-and-write-from-hive')
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate())
df_load = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM example")
df_load.show()
print(time.time() - start_time)
```

Which caused following runtime exception for missing jars.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBSerDe not found
```

How do I convert the `pyspark --jars..` to a pythonic equivalent.

As of now I tried copying the jars from the location `/usr/share/...` to `$SPARK_HOME/libs/jars` and adding that path to spark-defaults.conf external class path that had no effect.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49528031/10949092) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use spark-submit command to execute your python script. Example :

```
spark-submit --jars /usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hive.jar,/usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar script.py
```