# How can I read in XML files from S3 bucket on EMR?

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have stored XML files in S3 bucket and want to read them on EMR after typing:

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "Profile").load(xml_file_path)
```

It gave me errors:

> An error occurred while calling o445.load.
>   : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.xml. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

Comment: you need to specify the path to external jar e.g.: `pyspark --jars spark-xml_2.11-0.6.0.jar`. For more detailed answers have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698111/how-to-add-third-party-java-jars-for-use-in-pyspark

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the spark-xml library on your running EMR cluster with Spark .[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60298628/install-com-databricks-spark-xml-on-emr-cluster)
2. Launch a PySpark notebook
3. Execute the following:

> df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rootTag='objects').options(rowTag='object').load("s3://bucket-name/sample.xml")