# Read avro files in pyspark with PyCharm

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I'm quite new to spark, I've imported pyspark library to pycharm venv and write below code:

```
# Imports
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('DataFrame') \
    .master('local[*]') \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 5)
path = "file_path"
df = spark.read.format("avro").load(path)
```

, everything seems to be okay but when I want to read avro file I get message:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Failed to find data source: avro. Avro is built-in but external data source module since Spark 2.4. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Apache Avro Data Source Guide".;'

When I go to this page: >https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html there is something like this:

[image]

and I have no idea have to implement this, download something in PyCharm or you have to find external files to modify?

Thank you for help!

**Update (2019-12-06):**
Because I'm using Anaconda I've opened Anaconda prompt and copied this code:

```
pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0
```

It downloaded some modules, then I've got back to PyCharm and same error appears.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add third party java jars for use in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698111/how-to-add-third-party-java-jars-for-use-in-pyspark)

Comment: It makes some sense but I don't have any *.jar files, should I download something?

Comment: That would be an option, yes. You can find those packages typically on [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/).

Comment: @cincin21  can you directly use --package and run with spark-submit with --packages

Comment: can you try launching your pyspark shell like this and try running the code again `pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0`

Comment: ok, so because I'm using anaconda, I've copied this code to anaconda prompt and it downloaded some modules, then I've got back to PyCharm and same error appears

Comment: Check the pycharm environment whether you're using the same environment or different than the one, you have downloaded the package into.

Comment: I've checked it and everything was ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded the `pyspark` version `2.4.4` package from conda in PyCharm. And added `spark-avro_2.11-2.4.4.jar` file in spark configuration and was able to sucessfully recreate your error i.e, `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Failed to find data source: avro. Avro is built-in but external data source module since Spark 2.4. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Apache Avro Data Source Guide".;'`

To fix this issue, follow below steps:

1. Uninstall pyspark package downloaded from conda.
2. Download and unzip `spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz` from [here](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html).
3. In Run > Environment Varibales, you should set `SPARK_HOME` to `<download_path>/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7` and set `PYTHONPATH` to `$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:$SPARK_HOME/python`
4. Download `spark-avro_2.11-2.4.4.jar` file from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-avro_2.11/2.4.4).

Now you should be able to run pyspark code from PyCharm. Try below code:

```py
# Imports
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

#Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('DataFrame') \
    .master('local[*]')\
    .config('spark.jars', '<path>/spark-avro_2.11-2.4.4.jar') \
    .getOrCreate()


df = spark.read.format('avro').load('<path>/userdata1.avro')

df.show()
```

The above code will work but PyCharm will complain about pyspark modules. To remove that and enable code completion feature follow below additional steps:

1. In Project Structure, click on Add Content root and add `spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip`

Now your project structure should look like:

[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hi, I've done this step by step but now it does not see pyspark, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'` appears even after your additional step.

Comment: @cincin21 are you able to run the code atleast? If you haven't tried can you try running the code and let me know. If you are able to run the code and getting error only in Pycharm identifying pyspark you should add `/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python` to content root and then try if it works.

Comment: added 2nd path, seems ok now! Great work, could you only change "2.4.3" to "2.4.4" in some places of your walkthrough to keep it for the future users? best!

Answer (score 1):

`pyspark --jars /<path_to>/spark-avro_<version>.jar`
works for me with Spark 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution can be submitting the module in `Terminal` tab inside pycharm with `spark-submit` command as below.

General syntax of command:

`spark-submit --packages <package_name> <script_path>`

As avro is the package needed `com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0` package should be included. So the final command will be

`spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0 <script_path>`

Comment: One main thing I missed.
While reading the dataframe, format should be ```com.databricks.spark.avro``` not simple ```avro``` like this
```df=spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.avro').load('<path>/user.avro')```

Comment: @j raj -> I've tried this option and strange java error appeared: `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.load`. But maybe it will work on another machine ...

Comment: May i know the error? Usually, the error reason comes right after the statement you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: It says: `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`

Comment: Error says, the program is trying to read a file of ```org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat``` format which is incorrect. Could you specify ```com.databricks.spark.avro``` as format and execute. It should work.

Comment: I'm using `df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.avro').load(path)` , is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes.It should work. If it is not, i am not sure how to fix it. Sorry. :(

Comment: Sure, thank you for help, the above example works so I'm happy ;)

Comment: Avro is included in latest Spark from a separate package. Don't use the databricks one anymore

Answer (score 0):

Your Spark version and your avro JAR version should be in sync

ex: If you're using spark 3.1.2 and your avro jar version should be spark-avro_2.12-3.1.2.jar

Sample Code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('DataFrame').\
        config('spark.jars','C:\\Users\\<<User_Name>>\\Downloads\\spark-avro_2.12-3.1.2.jar').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format('avro').load('C:\\Users\\<<user name>>\\Downloads\\sample.avro')
df.show()

Output:
+-------------------+-------+------+------------+------------+--------------------+-------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------+------------------+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------------------+
|           datetime|country|region|publisher_id|placement_id|       impression_id|consent|   hostname|                uuid|placement_type_id|iab_device_type_id|site_id|request_type|placement_type|bid_url_domain|app_bundle|                 tps|
+-------------------+-------+------+------------+------------+--------------------+-------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------+------------------+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------------------+
|2021-07-30 14:55:18|   null|  null|        5016|        5016|8bdf2cf1-3a17-473...|      4|test.server|9515d578-9ee0-462...|                0|                 5|   5016|      advast|         video|          null|      null|{5016 -> {5016, n...|
|2021-07-30 14:55:22|   null|  null|        2702|        2702|ab3b63d1-a916-4d7...|      4|test.server|9515d578-9ee0-462...|                1|                 2|   2702|         adi|        banner|          null|      null|{2702 -> {2702, n...|
|2021-07-30 14:55:24|   null|  null|        1106|        1106|574f078f-0fc6-452...|      4|test.server|9515d578-9ee0-462...|                1|                 2|   1106|         adi|        banner|          null|      null|{1106 -> {1106, n...|
|2021-07-30 14:55:25|   null|  null|        1107|        1107|54bf5cf8-3438-400...|      4|test.server|9515d578-9ee0-462...|                1|                 2|   1107|         adi|        banner|          null|      null|{1107 -> {1107, n...|
|2021-07-30 14:55:27|   null|  null|        4277|        4277|b3508668-3ad5-4db...|      4|test.server|9515d578-9ee0-462...|                1|                 2|   4277|         adi|        banner|          null|      null|{4277 -> {4277, n...|
+-------------------+-------+------+------------+------------+--------------------+-------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------+------------------+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------------------+
```