How to read from S3 on PySpark on local
I'm trying to read CSVs stored in an S3 bucket. I have Apache Spark 3.5.1 installed with Homebrew. I have downloaded the Hadoop AWS connector and copied it to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.5.1/libexec/jars
Then, using the following code, I try to read the CSVs from S3:
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Base Spark Template").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

df2 = spark.read.csv("s3://arapbi/polygon/tickers/", header=True)


This fails with
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.csv.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3"
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1(DataSource.scala:724)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:722)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:551)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:404)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:538)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

The first line of that error trace is the important one; Spark doesn't recognize S3.
My understanding, however, is that Spark should be able to recognize S3, based on the connector I downloaded and the jar file I copied to the Spark Jars folder when Spark is installed via Homebrew.
Am I mistaken in which Jar file to use, or how to configure this in general? I followed these same steps with the Google Storage connector and it worked correctly.
I've Googled and searched Stack Overflow to no avail. I'll update the question with an answer if I find it, but if anyone's managed to set up Brew-installed PySpark to connect to S3, please let the rest of us know how!
UPDATE 04-04-2024
Per stevel's answer, I modified df2 = spark.read.csv("s3://arapbi/polygon/tickers/", header=True) to df2 = spark.read.csv("s3a://arapbi/polygon/tickers/", header=True). This changed the source of the error in the Stacktrace (see below), but still didn't work.
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o68.csv.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/core/exception/SdkException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2625)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2590)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:538)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 31 more


https://blog.revolve.team/2023/05/02/data-files-from-s3-in-local-pyspark-environment/ this could help

I tried what the author described and it did not work...

Also can you post the steps you take to run the above script? Do you run it directly from PyCharm ? Have you installed pyspark package in your virutal environment or python environment?

You have to first update the hadoop jars from v3.4.0 to v3.3.4 jars with Spark 3.5.1 as it is compiled with Hadoop v3.3.4 as described in  source code.
Secondly, update the s3 URI scheme to s3a URI scheme as Hadoop supports only s3a client. Try setting the below configuration in your code.
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Base Spark Template").getOrCreate()
    
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider,com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain") # Change it according to your auth mechanism

df2 = spark.read.csv("s3a://arapbi/polygon/tickers/", header=True)


I tried this and it did not work...

Can you share the error?

it doesn't work because all the recommendations are wrong

Same error as before @NishuTayal

Well, I am using the same code with Spark 3.5.1. Yes, you need to ensure that all the required jars are in place and added to classpath.  (hadoop-aws-3.3.4.jar, hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar, hadoop-client-runtime-3.3.4.jar, hadoop-shaded-guava-1.1.1.jar)

I've made sure the same jars are available. I'm getting An error occurred while calling o50.csv. : org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3". This is so confusing

Nishu, you were absolutely correct and the problem was that I was using hadoop-aws-3.4.0.jar instead of hadoop-aws-3.3.4.jar. Thank you so much! (Also note that the s3 prefix should be s3a not s3 as others pointed out

@Evan : Great to hear that. Also to add here - Spark 3.5.1 is compiled with Hadoop 3.3.4 version as described in dependencies pom.xml. That's why it didn't work to you the Hadoop v3.4.0 jars.

Nishu, I think you are missing the point. Everyone of those hadoopConfiguration options are either needs (fs.s3a.impl;, or fundamentally wrong "com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4" was a system property needed for hadoop 2.6 to talk to aws regions which only support v4 signing. s3a connector doesn't need this, and if it did, the hadoop configuration is not the place to put it in. please read the hadoop s3a documentation which I put a lot of effort into writing rather than just believe other people's stack overflow comments

apache hadoop uses the s3a connector, not the EMR one.

All s3 urls must use s3a: as the prefix
there are lots of SO posts about getting classpaths right. All your hadoop-* jars must be in sync and you need the same version of the aws sdk as it was built with. If that isn't working: search stack overflow.


I've updated my question above with the difference in the stacktraces when using s3 and s3a. I'm not sure I understand "you need the same version of the aws sdk as it was built with."  What does "it" refer to, exactly? Also, is the aws sdk an additional jar file that needs to be added to the spark jars folder, in addition to hadoop-aws-3.4.0.jar?  Maybe this is an issue of I'm not including all the jars I need to?

The reason is the Hadoop version. Spark 3.5.1 is compiled with Hadoop v3.3.4 and OP had used Hadoop v3.4.0. Hence it gives the error.

yes I did say exactly that, didn't I?

As per updated question, the recent AWS emr release is emr-7.0.0
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-app-versions-7.x.html
It uses latest spark version : Spark    3.5.0
For that spark version it uses AWS Java SDK version : 1.12.569
These details are given on the above webpage.
So it is VERY IMPORTANT that use Spark 3.5.0 version because the AWS jars have been built using that verison of spark.
To get all the dependencies and so on, download the full jar bundle from below.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.12.569
You can manually download the bundle under Files section..
Files   pom (5 KB)  jar (331.7 MB)  View All

Once the bundle is downloaded, put the jar in
/python3.X/site-packages/pyspark/jars
Read this answer for more details :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51537182/3238085
More trouble shooting steps here :
https://codelovingyogi.medium.com/pyspark-connect-to-aws-s3a-filesystem-82bee54e0812

I did as you said and I'm still getting An error occurred while calling o40.csv. : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/core/exception/SdkException. Per @Nishu's response, I also made sure I've got each of hadoop-aws-3.3.4.jar, hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar, hadoop-client-runtime-3.3.4.jar, hadoop-shaded-guava-1.1.1.jar

how are you running the pyspark script? from Pycharm ?

iPython. Does that make a difference?

did you do pip install pyspark?

I installed it via Homebrew, as I noted in my question, and launch it via pyspark on the command line. My zsh is configured with... 135 export SPARK_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.5.1/libexec 136 export PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.5.1/bin:$PATH 137 export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 138 export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython

Can you locate the pyspark jars directory within your python environment? Since pyspark is self sufficient installation, your apache-spark installation doesn't matter

I never pip installed pyspark. I used Homebrew. The jars are located at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.5.1/libexec/jars. I've successfully placed BigQuery and Google Storage jars in this location and been able to query both. I think I'm missing a jar file somewhere for AWS, but I can't figure out where that is

ok lets try this pyspark --packages "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.12.569" app.py . Before doing this install pyspark 3.5.0 because sdk only works with 3.5.0. And you have apache-spark/3.5.1/

all my pyspark jars are located here /conda_envs/pyspark-example/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/jars  on a linux machine. MacOS pyspark might have similar structure.

The problem is that Spark 3.5.0 is no longer available for download https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

It seems you are using pyspark from apache-spark/bin directory or equivalent in mac. But you can directly install pyspark in your python environment. pip install pyspark==3.5.0 . This will install that specific version. The version is still availabe in archieved section. https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/

I attempted with Spark 3.5.0 (double checked via spark.version in Ipython) and I'm still getting the same software/amazon/awssdk/core/exception/SdkException error as before. I copied all the relevant jars to the virtual env's copy of Spark, and also ran brew uninstall apache-spark just to be extra certain I was running against Spark 3.5.0. As before, Google's jars work just fine. The AWS jars aren't allowing me to connect to s3.

I just fixed it. The (latest) problem was that I was using the wrong jar file. I needed to be using hadoop-aws-3.3.4.jar instead of hadoop-aws-3.4.0.jar. I'm in the process of testing this further to see if it works with Spark 3.5.1.

Everything works, even Spark 3.5.1, as a result of using hadoop-aws-3.3.4.jar.
