S3AFileSystem not found: Accessing s3 files on EC2 using notebooks
There are multiple answers around this problem like this and this. I went through both and couldn't get the problem resolved. This is the summary:

I have an EC2 cloned using this AMI: "Deep Learning AMI GPU TensorFlow 2.11.0 (Ubuntu 20.04)"

I connected to this instance through ssh, launched a jupyter notebook.

!pip install pyspark import pyspark

Did the spark config:
sc = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()  conf = SparkConf().setAppName("SMB_classification") sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key",ACCESS_KEY) sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", SECRET_KEY) sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com") sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true") sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().setInt("fs.s3a.connection.maximum", 100) sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.buffer.dir", "/var/tmp/spark") spark = SparkSession(sc)

df=spark.read.parquet('s3a://s3path/file.parquet')


I get the error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found 
I cannot see spark or hadoop in my EC2.

Have you added the Hadoop jars in your Spark classpath?

I havent installed Spark, will I have spark classpath ?

Yeah, you will still need to make the external jars available to your Spark context some. You can either add those to python3.x/site-packages/pyspark/jars or pass in your spark conf in python code.

This question and answers below it will be helpful to you. Also read the comments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78269281/how-to-read-from-s3-on-pyspark-on-local/
Having correct versions of the jar is very important.

Thank you @NishuTayal and user238607  - I am in the process of putting the right jars. However, with just pip install pyspark, how do we know the right versions of hadoop jars that are required?

You should check which Spark version is installed. Based on that you can find the compatible jar versions on Internet, Spark documentations.

Does this answer your question? java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StorageStatistics

This is how I resolved the problem:
As explained in the question, I used this AMI to launch my ec2:
Deep Learning AMI GPU TensorFlow 2.11.0 (Ubuntu 20.04)
On Jupyter notebook, I installed pyspark as below:
!pip install pyspark
import pyspark

I did the standard spark set up.
################################# Spark Config ############################################
sc = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Classifier")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key",key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "Cloud Object Storage - Amazon S3  - AWS ")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A")

sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().setInt("fs.s3a.connection.maximum", 100)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.buffer.dir", "/var/tmp/spark")

sql = SQLContext(sc)

spark = SparkSession(sc)

Now, I tried to access a dataset in s3.
df=spark.read.parquet('s3a://bucket/train_data.parquet')

Got the error that “java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found."
How did I solve?
Found that python and related files are here: “/opt/tensorflow/lib/python3.10” ( How do you find out where python is ? - which python/find / -name “python”).
Next, find the pyspark version - pyspark.version : 3.5.1.
How to find the jars ? ( honest answer - Stackoverflow : hadoop-aws and aws-java-sdk version compatibility for Spark 3.1.2 , AWS SDK: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError  ,S3AFileSystem not found: Accessing s3 files on EC2 using notebooks. I didnt go beyond)
Which are the jars ? I added these jars
aws-java-sdk-1.12.696.jar
aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.696.jar
hadoop-aws-3.3.4.jar
hadoop-common-3.4.0.jar
Where should we put the jars?
/opt/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/jars/
